# java: how to convert a file to utf8

Tags: java, utf-8

i have a file that have some non-utf8 caracters (like "ISO-8859-1"), and so i want to convert that file (or read) to UTF8 encoding, how i can do it?

The code it's like this:

```
File file = new File("some_file_with_non_utf8_characters.txt");

/* some code to convert the file to an utf8 file */

...
```

edit: Put an encoding example

Comment: Non-UTF8?  Want to narrow that down a bit?  It's easy once you know the input encoding, and essentially impossible if you don't.

Comment: some considerations, the files are BIG (like 1GB) so i can't put them in a String object...

Comment: what is your file's encoding? If you're on Linux or OS X (and other Un*x) you can just type:   *file some_file*  and it shall tell you the encoding.   Btw, if you're on Un*x (at least both Linux and OS X), you should have the *iconv* command line.  *"man iconv"* says: *"Convert encoding of given files from one encoding to another"*, which arguably will do a better job on a 1GB file than a self-written Java util.  Note that the UTF-8 encoding can represent every single Unicode codepoint, hence saying that the file *"has some non-utf8 characters"* sounds dubious...

Comment: @NoozNooz42: The application will run in win32 and unix/linux

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  String charset = "ISO-8859-1"; // or what corresponds
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( 
      new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream(file), charset));
  String line;
  while( (line = in.readLine()) != null) { 
    ....
  }
```

There you have the text decoded. You can write it, by the simmetric Writer/OutputStream methods, with the encoding you prefer (eg UTF-8).

Comment: the potential problem with reading line-by-line is that you can alter line endings / separations.  For example, if the last line has no end-of-line, you will add one.

Comment: That's totally true. It's also true that frequently that effect is actually desirable (more a "polishing" than an "alteration"). But, yes, one must be aware of that.

Comment: Hi, what if I don't know the source/input encoding format? Can you please throw some light on it.

Answer (score 19):

The following code converts a file from srcEncoding to tgtEncoding:

```
public static void transform(File source, String srcEncoding, File target, String tgtEncoding) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(source),srcEncoding));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(target), tgtEncoding));
        char[] buffer = new char[16384];
        int read;
        while ((read = br.read(buffer)) != -1)
            bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } finally {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**--EDIT--**

Using Try-with-resources (Java 7):

```
public static void transform(File source, String srcEncoding, File target, String tgtEncoding) throws IOException {
    try (
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(source), srcEncoding));
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(target), tgtEncoding)); ) {
          char[] buffer = new char[16384];
          int read;
          while ((read = br.read(buffer)) != -1)
              bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ignore my comment, you are right. Btw, haven't seen this style of closing in finally before. Clever.

Answer (score 5):

You need to know the encoding of the input file. For example, if the file is in Latin-1, you would do something like this,

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.in");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1");
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.out");
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
            out.write(ch);
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
```

Comment: Summarized: **read** it in the file's own encoding and then **write** it in the new encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to read it as UTF-8?
What I did recently given a similar problem is to start the JVM with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, and reading/printing as normal. I don't know if that is applicable in your case.

With that option:

```
System.out.println("á é í ó ú")
```

prints correctly the characters. Otherwise it prints a ? symbol

Comment: @McD: I was going to post the same comment. This is a misinterpretation of the use of the `-Dfile.encoding`.