# ??? Questions Marks in Meta Tags in Social Web Crawlers for AngularJS application using Prerender.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a site that generates meta tags containing Japanese characters as part of the Open Graph protocol.  However, when running the site

https://www.inkgrph.com/e/210

through an crawler, namely

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

the meta tag `content` attribute's Japanese characters all show up as ??????? under "Raw Open Graph Document Information"

Other sites such as

http://tabelog.com/

seem to display Japanese characters fine in the meta tags.  I've tried setting

`lang="ja" xml:lang="ja"`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ja">`

in the html with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know exactly what is happening. But I checked your page response headers, and in the ``content-type`` header is missing a charset. Try set your ``content-type`` header to ``content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8``

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that that site doesn't have a charset in its response, so Facebook has to assume a charset, and it probably assumes ANSI which simply converts any unknown characters to question marks. Depending on the language, implementations differ, but you can probably find the instructions on how to do it by googling "HTTP header charset *language*". Your HTTP header should be something like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

An example to make this work, in PHP it's simply:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and then Facebook will know the charset is UTF-8 so it won't convert the Japanese characters to question marks anymore. [W3 also made a short list of code examples](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset#scripting).

I've tested this myself to verify, and when I made a file that replied with this same header, Facebook did handle the Japanese characters correctly.

---

Going by your comment that the actual URL crawlers use https://www.inkgrph.com/e/210?_escaped_fragment_=, I can see why Facebook thinks the characters are question marks: it's because they are. When I open that page in my browser, it also shows the question marks. That means that the problem is on your server, not Facebook's processing of the page.

What's the problem now, most likely, is that your server does indeed *reply* that the content-type is UTF-8, but that the actual content-type on the server is still ASCII, so it changes the Japanese characters on the server.

To fix this, you should simply make sure all the files on your server are stored in UTF-8 encoding. In the future, it might be useful to set your default character encoding to UTF-8 ([here's how to do it in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423450/1256925), and [this is for Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16199148/1256925); try googling for your own text editor). For now though, you're going to have to change the chararacter encoding yourself. You can either do that manually, or try googling for ways to do it automatically.

What I've found is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64860/1256925) which already covers automated charencoding conversion. You could also try [this Notepad++ / Python approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64860/1256925), but if you try to google more specifically per language ("*Convert files to UTF-8 Python*" for example), you can easily find ways to do it ([Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/191359/1256925), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3018653/1256925)).

Comment: I wasn't sure if was that. So I left as a comment. Upvote for you!

Comment: I thought that was the issue, but the actual page Facebook sees is actually https://www.inkgrph.com/e/210?_escaped_fragment_= which does have the `Content-Type` header.  

I'm actually using Phantom-JS to cache my pages for crawling since my metadata are all generated via Javascript.

Comment: @Luke does this addition help? If changing your charencoding on your files doesn't work, please tell me, so I can have another look at what your page looks like after the conversion.