# Invalid UTF8 encoding on processing xml file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, spring-batch

I have a Java code that process an XML file  to read some values. I got an error : **Invalid UTF8 encoding** , I tried to copy the file contents  in an other file on NotePad++ , the process worked fine but if I only save the file as an other name it's give the same error.
Sorry, I can not put my XML file here because it is too big I will put only the header and trailer . 
Any help is appreciated  to resolve this error. 
my java code to process xml file :

```
XPathFactory f=XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath x=f.newXPath();

    InputSource source=new InputSource(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cc\\eclipse-workspace\\data\\file.xml") );
    InputSource source2=new InputSource(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cc\\eclipse-workspace\\data\\file.xml") );

    XPathExpression trlr=x.compile("pers/trailer/text()");
    XPathExpression hdr=x.compile("pers/header/CD/text()");

    String s=trlr.evaluate(source);
    String s2=hdr.evaluate(source2);
    System.out.println("header :"+s+" trailer"+s2);
```

pers is the root tag in the  xml file:

XML file  looks like this :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<pers>
 <header>555</header>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 <trailer>666</trailer>

</pers>
```

stack trace :

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid UTF8 encoding.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLUTF8Reader.checkUTF8Byte(XMLUTF8Reader.java:229)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLUTF8Reader.readUTF8Char(XMLUTF8Reader.java:274)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLUTF8Reader.fillBuffer(XMLUTF8Reader.java:189)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLByteReader.saveBuffer(XMLByteReader.java:452)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.fillBuffer(XMLReader.java:2776)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.scanNameChars(XMLReader.java:1352)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.readQName(XMLReader.java:2149)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1579)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:448)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:394)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:236)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:175)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:332)
    at tasklets.HeaderFooter.execute(HeaderFooter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at main.IncomeResponseFile.main(IncomeResponseFile.java:39)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid UTF8 encoding.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:332)
    at tasklets.HeaderFooter.execute(HeaderFooter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at main.IncomeResponseFile.main(IncomeResponseFile.java:39)
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid UTF8 encoding.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLUTF8Reader.checkUTF8Byte(XMLUTF8Reader.java:229)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLUTF8Reader.readUTF8Char(XMLUTF8Reader.java:274)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLUTF8Reader.fillBuffer(XMLUTF8Reader.java:189)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLByteReader.saveBuffer(XMLByteReader.java:452)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.fillBuffer(XMLReader.java:2776)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.scanNameChars(XMLReader.java:1352)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.readQName(XMLReader.java:2149)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1579)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:448)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:394)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:236)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:175)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:302)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Is the file really UTF-8? Any special characters?

Comment: I'd recommend posting the stack trace as well. Maybe you have some extended characters that come from a non-unicode source and get converted somehow when pasting the text into np++ and saving a new file?

Comment: @ Mena , I updated with stack trace

Comment: @ piet.t , It's hard to say , the file have around 100 000 record(pers) and each record 100 field  which is numbers and strings.

Comment: Nothing is ever easy, but I guess you'll have to find that one offending character and check its encoding via a hex-editor. And always keep in mind: just because an xml-file claims to be UTF-8 in it's headers it is not necessarily true.

Comment: @OmarB. the stack trace doesn't help much after all... If I understand you correctly, you claim copying the contents into a new npp file and saving it will work with that new file. If that's true, then compare the source and the destination with a specialized tool (might need hex/binary) to find out the differences(s) at byte level. Might be some painful trial and error.

Comment: @ Mena ,yes that is correct . I will try to find a tool to compare . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to convert the file to UTF-8 format  :

```
 File source = new File("C:\\Users\\cc\\eclipse-workspace\\data\\file.xml");
    String srcEncoding="ISO-8859-1";
    File target = new File("C:\\Users\\cc\\eclipse-workspace\\data\\file2.xml");
    String tgtEncoding="UTF-8";
      try (
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(source), srcEncoding));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(target), tgtEncoding)); ) {
            char[] buffer = new char[16384];
            int read;
            while ((read = br.read(buffer)) != -1)
                bw.write(buffer, 0, read);

  }
```

after that I used file2 it worked . thanks to : [java: how to convert a file to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018653/java-how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf8)

Answer (score 2):

Use java for scripting to detect the problematic line.

```
AtomicInteger lineno = new AtomicInteger();
Path path = Paths.get("... .xml");
Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
    .forEach(line -> {
        int no = lineno.incrementAndGet();
        byte[] b = line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        try {
            new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n%s%n", no, line, e.getMessage());
            //throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    });
```

One may assume it is a data error.

In general it could also be erroneous, buffered reading: when a mult-byte sequence is broken on a buffer boundary; then two wrong half sequences could arise. Unlikely in standard library code.

---

To ensure the code of `new String(...)` does not get discarded by the JVM, maybe:

```
int sowhat = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
    .mapToInt(line -> {
        int no = lineno.incrementAndGet();
        byte[] b = line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        try {
            return new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n%s%n", no, line, e.getMessage());
            throw new IllegalStateException(e); // Must throw or return int
        }
    }).sum();
System.out.println("Ignore this: " + sowhat);
```

One may assume it is a data error.

In general it could also be erroneous, buffered reading: when a mult-byte sequence is broken on a buffer boundary; then two wrong half sequences could arise. Unlikely in standard library code.

---

To ensure the code of `new String(...)` does not get discarded by the JVM, maybe:

```
int sowhat = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
    .mapToInt(line -> {
        int no = lineno.incrementAndGet();
        byte[] b = line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        try {
            return new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n%s%n", no, line, e.getMessage());
            throw new IllegalStateException(e); // Must throw or return int
        }
    }).sum();
```

---

***Illegal XML characters (in version 1.0)?*** [#x1-#x8] | [#xB-#xC] | [#xE-#x1F] | [#x7F-#x84] | [#x86-#x9F]

```
int sowhat = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
    .mapToInt(line -> {
        int no = lineno.incrementAndGet();
        byte[] b = line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        if (!legal(b)) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %s%n%s%n", no, line, e.getMessage());
            throw new IllegalStateException(e); // Must throw or return int
        }
    }).sum();

static boolean legal(byte[] bytes) {
    String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        int x = ch;
        if ((0 <= x && x <= 8)               // ASCII control chars
                || (0xB <= x && x <= 0xC)
                || (0xE <= x && x <= 0x1F)
                || (0x7f <= x && x <= 0x84)  // DEL + Unicode control chars
                || (0x86 <= x && x <= 0x9F)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Should this not work, I have kept you long enough. Split the file and validate the parts.

Comment: thanks for the answer , I tried  this java code , but didn t give any error.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, the JVM skips `new String(...)`. So I added a variation. The stacktrace seems to point to a tag or more likely to an attribute name. In XML version 1.0 there should be no non-ASCII letters like `é`, so that is weird.

Comment: I got this : Ignore this: 134087631 ,  I don t understand that . what that mean ?

Comment: Just that it run through every line with a successful conversion to UTF-8. So there must be another error. There are illegal XML characters, maybe the error is misleading.

Comment: Added the code for the obvious illegal XML chars, but one can continue this way for a couple more of causes. Maybe it is just a spurious `<` or `&#128;` in user data.