# Android convert charset

Tags: java, android, charset

How can I convert this "Predajnďż˝" (Windows-1250) to "Predajňa" (UTF-8) or fix "Predajn�" to "Predajňa" in android.

I am using Java as programming language and Android Studio as an IDE to do this.

I didn't find anything so can someone help me to do this?

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE, what do you mean by converting charset? Where is it `Predajnďż˝` but should be `Predajňa`?

Comment: "Predajnďż˝" is in txt file and i want to convert it Predajňa (UTF-8)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018653/java-how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf8

Comment: I tested it but when i  put there String charset = "UTF-8"; then the text remains the same "Predajnďż˝"